# ActionMailer throws an error while attaching files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I have ActionMailer working and sending plain emails.
But when I try to attach a file, I get: `#<Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xFF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8> - nil`

My snippet for doing that is:

```
mail(subject: "test test",
         from: "o@myemail.com",
         to: ["b@reciepient.com"],
         date: Time.now,
         content_type: "text/html",
         attachments[file[:filename]] => file[:data] )
```

Any suggestion what may go wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is normally generated when you try to attach a file handler without using binary mode but the file is not a text file.

I can't see in the code where you create the file handler. You should use `wb` to open it.

```
File.open(path, 'wb')
```

instead of

```
File.open(path, 'w')
```

Keep in mind that if the attachment is not a text file, the content_type also is wrong.

What type of file where you attaching?

Comment: Hi. I attached PDF or JPEG. actually, I've removed the content_type altogether and it is working!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base

def my_mailing_method
  attachments[file[:filename]] => file[:data]
  mail(subject: "test test",
         from: "o@myemail.com",
         to: ["b@reciepient.com"],
         date: Time.now,
         content_type: "text/html")
end
```

Comment: Thanks! could you please elaborate why this is the fix?

Comment: It is result of my own experience. No sure what is under the hood but this is basically about proper mime-type setting in the email. This sequence makes the thing at least for me.